# In android's use Messenger between process, is MessageQueue not used?

Tags: android, handler, message-queue, messenger

I have some question about Messenger communication.
it look both sides can use Messenger + Handler to communicate each other.
However, I don't find they need to create MessageQueue.  does it mean MessageQueue is not created in this case? does Messenger itself maintain message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create Handlers within `Activities`, `Services` and other such components that extend `Context`.
The handlers use `Context.getMainLooper()` and that `Looper` has its message queue `Looper.getQueue()`
You can not create a Handler from something which doesn't have a `Looper`, there will be a runtime exception.

Comment: To add to this-  the main thread is set up with a Looper and a MessageQueue already.  Handlers are associated with the thread they're created on-  whatever thread they are created on, they get the Looper associated with it (if any), and send their messages to that Looper's Message queue.  If there is no Looper on the Thread you call new Handler() on, then an excetion will be thrown.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.